# Accidentally created a model called "Set" -- how to fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a project that displays concerts, bands and the sets they play. I scaffolded a model named `Set`, which was obviously stupid of me because there's already a `Set` class in Ruby.

So, my question is: what's the best way fix this problem? Should I just destroy the scaffold? Is that my only option, really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename all the files (and classes) but destroying scaffolding will be faster :)

Comment: But doing it all by hand would be a good learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

When you scaffold, a migration is created. You can migrate down the version to rollback the Set scaffold (if you already do a db:migrate) :

```
./script/generate scaffold Set foo:string bar:string
      exists  app/models/
      exists  app/controllers/
      exists  app/helpers/
      create  app/views/sets
      exists  app/views/layouts/
      exists  test/functional/
      exists  test/unit/
          create  test/unit/helpers/
      exists  public/stylesheets/
      create  app/views/sets/index.html.erb
      create  app/views/sets/show.html.erb
      create  app/views/sets/new.html.erb
      create  app/views/sets/edit.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/sets.html.erb
      create  public/stylesheets/scaffold.css
      create  app/controllers/sets_controller.rb
      create  test/functional/sets_controller_test.rb
      create  app/helpers/sets_helper.rb
      create  test/unit/helpers/sets_helper_test.rb
       route  map.resources :sets
  dependency  model
      exists    app/models/
      exists    test/unit/
      exists    test/fixtures/
      create    app/models/set.rb
      create    test/unit/set_test.rb
      create    test/fixtures/sets.yml
      create    db/migrate
      create    db/migrate/20110328204128_create_sets.rb
```

Be careful to this line :

```
      create    db/migrate/20110328204128_create_sets.rb
```

It provides the number of the migration : 20110328204128

To rollback the transaction :

```
rake db:migrate:down VERSION=20110328204128
```

---

The last step :

As flOOr said :

> You can rename all the files (and classes) but destroying scaffolding will be faster :)